# root of $a-b{{e}^{cx}}-{{e}^{\left( c+d \right)x}}=0$

Tags: roots

I am trying to find the root(s) of this equation, basically write variable x in terms of parameters a, b, c, and d. not sure how to proceed. Thanks!

$$a-b{{e}^{cx}}-{{e}^{\left( c+d \right)x}}=0$$

Comment: Are $c$ and $d$ positive integers?

Comment: There will be atmost one real root depending on the signs of the constants $a,b,c,d$, but there is no simple expression for the root in terms of $a,b,c,d$ I think.

Comment: @sciona Im CERTAIN of it.

Comment: This can be written as solving $a-bz^c-z^{c+d}=0$, the take $x=\ln z$. It probably can't be solved in general in a closed form using usual functions.